# Can't retrieve custom post type data through REST API using get_post()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get data from a custom post type single post through `REST API`. With `get_posts()` it works fine:

```
function single_project($data) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page'=> 1,
    'p' => $data
  );  
  return get_posts($args);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'project/v1', 'post/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'single_project',
    'args' => [
      'id'
    ]
  ));
});
```

But in my front-end I get an array and I have to get the data from the first and only item of that array, which is not nice.

`get_post()` sounds like the solution but for some reason it doesn't work: the ID doesn't get passed through REST API and I can't see why.

```
function single_project($data) {
  return get_post($data);
}
```

The `add_action() { ... }` code is identical.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation ([Adding Custom Endpoints | WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)) you'll notice that `$data` is actually an array and so your code fails to do what you expect it to do because you're passing an array to the [get_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) function which expects either an integer (the post ID) or a `WP_Post` object instead.

So:

```
function single_project($data) {
  $post_ID = $data['id'];
  return get_post($post_ID);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'project/v1', 'post/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'single_project',
    'args' => [
      'id'
    ]
  ));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_route');
function my_register_route() {

      register_rest_route( 'my-route', 'my-posts/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'my_posts',
            'args' => array(
                    'id' => array( 
                        'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                            return is_numeric( $param );
                        }
                    ),
                ),
            'permission_callback' => function() {
                return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
                }, 
        );
}

function my_posts( $data ) {

    // default the author list to all
    $post_author = 'all';

    // if ID is set
    if( isset( $data[ 'id' ] ) ) {
          $post_author = $data[ 'id' ];
    }

    // get the posts
    $posts_list = get_posts( array( 'type' => 'post', 'author' => $post_author ) );
    $post_data = array();

    foreach( $posts_list as $posts) {
        $post_id = $posts->ID;
        $post_author = $posts->post_author;
        $post_title = $posts->post_title;
        $post_content = $posts->post_content;

        $post_data[ $post_id ][ 'author' ] = $post_author;
        $post_data[ $post_id ][ 'title' ] = $post_title;
        $post_data[ $post_id ][ 'content' ] = $post_content;
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return rest_ensure_response( $post_data );
}
```